# Setting up Postfix with Apache Virtual Hosts?

Tags: server, apache2, postfix

So, I was trying to setup multiple Apache Virtual Hosts. Everything was O.K, LAMP worked fine except for one and big problem: Postfix.

I have two domains. And two PHP/MySQL applications running on each virtual host, with it's own domain. 
E.g: I have OpenCart in domain1.com and WordPress in domain2.com, but PostFix send all OpenCart and WordPress mail from domain1.com OR domain2.com.

There's a way to "fix" it?

Comment: Do you run the applications (virtual hosts) as different OS users?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip No. The files are stored in /var/www/(domain)/public_html, running as default Amazon EC2 user, ubuntu. And the mail address is always ubuntu@domain1.com or ubuntu@domain2.com

Comment: Set up your application (Wordpress) to use a different sender address. This is not really a Ubuntu question, I'm afraid. Nor does it have anything to do with Apache's configuration. First hit on Google on Wordpress support: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-email-sender Hope this helps.